# Given two potatoes, prove that there is a loop of wire which fits around both

Tags: geometry, continuity, problem-solving

This is a classic problem in geometric continuity and I want to see if there are some solutions other than the one I'm thinking of:

Two potatoes are given. Prove that there exists a closed loop of wire (fixed length) that fits tightly around each potato.

A more mathematical way of saying this is: we are given two closed, non intersecting 3-dimensional surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$. Prove that there is some closed, non-intersecting path $p_1$ on $S_1$, and some closed, non-intersecting path $p_2$ on $S_2$, such that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are identical in shape.

Comment: To satisfy your "more mathematical" version, it seems like you could just take some very small simply connected neighborhood on each potato, stick tiny loops inside each neighborhood, and use the fact that they're simply connected to shrink the larger one until it's the length of the smaller one. I'm not sure this fulfills my intuition of what it means to "fit tightly", though; is there some condition I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry I did not mean length I meant in shape. Is there a word for that? (isomorphic or something?).

Comment: Ah, the wire isn't allowed to flex between the potatoes. That makes a lot more sense. I think your current wording is fine...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take your two potatoes, and intersect them. They'll intersect in a closed curve, which is your wire. (If they intersect in multiple closed curves, just pick one of them.)

Comment: I suppose one has to prove that they intersect in one or more closed curves.

Comment: Bloody hell, now that is what I call thinking. Here Vroomfondel, why do we never think of things like that?

Comment: @HenrySwanson: that is exactly the classic solution, except you need to do what Gerry Myerson suggests in order to be 100% correct.

Comment: The problem is that the loop is supposed to fit *around* both. I don't think it's actually possible, not in the intuitive way, anyway (consider two spherical potatoes of vastly different diameters).

Comment: @tomasz: Swanson proved its possible. If you take the loop to be the intersection, then it fits around both. In the case of two spheres, intersect the spheres and the resulting circle is the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, my geometric proofs are a lot worse than my geometric intuition. How would one prove that? You'd have to somehow avoid the case where two flat sides of the potatoes are flush against each other, which seems hard.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou: But the circle is quite clearly on the "side" of a sphere if the two are of very disparate sizes. Indeed, it can be so even for two of similar size.

Comment: @HenrySwanson: The technical way to do this would be via the [transversality theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem): originally they might not intersect in closed curves, but they will after you wiggle them around a bit (at least assuming your potatoes are smooth).